# error message in php in codeigniter, Undefined variable: data

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi all in model i gave in function as follows

```
$query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result();
            $data[] = $result;
```

but am getting error as   A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Undefined variable: data

Filename: models/survey_model.php

Line Number: 845

null

what was the for this. can someone help me please

```
function get_actual_details_model($fin_year,$state){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('survey_respondent_info');
        $this->db->where('state', $state);
        $queryYr = $this->db->get();
        $resYr = $queryYr->result();
        foreach ($resYr as  $surveyId) {
            $this->db->select('budgets.*, budget_funding.*, marketing_budget.*, personnel_budget.*, grants_budget.*');
            $this->db->from('budgets');
            $this->db->join('budget_funding', 'budget_funding.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
            $this->db->join('marketing_budget', 'marketing_budget.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
            $this->db->join('personnel_budget', 'personnel_budget.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
            $this->db->join('grants_budget', 'grants_budget.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
            $this->db->where('budgets.financial_year',$fin_year);
            $this->db->where('budget_option_id', 1);
            $this->db->where('survey_id', $surveyId->survey_id);
          $data = array();
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
$data[] = $result;
        }
        return $data;
      }
```

Comment: Where are you setting $data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2):

Example of code you should use. **It's only example!**

```
$data = array();
$query = $this->db->get( 'table' );
$result = $query->result();
$data[] = $result;

return $data;
```

Your code with little update

```
function get_actual_details_model($fin_year,$state){
    $data = array(); // Data need to be in start
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('survey_respondent_info');
    $this->db->where('state', $state);
    $queryYr = $this->db->get();
    $resYr = $queryYr->result();
    foreach ($resYr as  $surveyId) {
        $this->db->select('budgets.*, budget_funding.*, marketing_budget.*, personnel_budget.*, grants_budget.*');
        $this->db->from('budgets');
        $this->db->join('budget_funding', 'budget_funding.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('marketing_budget', 'marketing_budget.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('personnel_budget', 'personnel_budget.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('grants_budget', 'grants_budget.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('budgets.financial_year',$fin_year);
        $this->db->where('budget_option_id', 1);
        $this->db->where('survey_id', $surveyId->survey_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        $data[] = $result;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Show your all model, because, if it's same error, then problem is not there.

Comment: function get_actual_details_model($fin_year,$state){
     $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('survey_respondent_info');
  $this->db->where('state', $state);
  $queryYr = $this->db->get();
  $resYr = $queryYr->result();

Comment: foreach ($resYr as  $surveyId) {
   $this->db->select('budgets.*, budget_funding.*, marketing_budget.*, personnel_budget.*, grants_budget.*');
   $this->db->from('budgets');
   $this->db->join('budget_funding', 'budget_funding.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
   $this->db->join('marketing_budget', 'marketing_budget.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
      $this->db->join('personnel_budget', 'personnel_budget.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');
   $this->db->join('grants_budget', 'grants_budget.budget_id = budgets.budget_id', 'left');

Comment: Just edit your main post and put your code there in `CODE tags`

Comment: $this->db->where('budgets.financial_year',$fin_year);
   $this->db->where('budget_option_id', 1);
   $this->db->where('survey_id', $surveyId->survey_id);
          $data = array();
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
$data[] = $result;
  }
  return $data;
   }   it is showing as more characters so am sending total code by splitting.

Comment: You need to declare $data in start of function.

Comment: if am declaring in the starting am getting empty array as output

Comment: Debug your code. Start with what you get from `$result = $query->result();` in loop. Then debug final `return $data;`. In final, debug your controller, see if there you get information from model.

Comment: how to debug to know whether it is getting or not

Comment: For example use command from php. `var_dump` [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: i used in this way $query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
print_r ($query);exit;
$data[] = $result; but am not able to see that output

Comment: You store your result in variable $results, but trying to print $query. It's wrong. You need to debug variable where you store your data.

Comment: $query = $this->db->get();
   $result = $query->result();
   print_r ($result);exit; am giving in this way also it is not working arthur

Comment: If You don't get any data from your result, then check your query's. I guess there is the problem, because you don't get result from your DB.

Answer (score 2):

you have to define you `$data` first.

```
$data = array();
```

Change

```
$data[] = $result;
```

To

```
$data = $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you put anything in $data, define it as empty array like this:

```
$data = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$data` variable is not defined.
And it is appended with `$result`

Following is the updated code:

```
$data = array();
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
$data[] = $result;
```